# `react-native init` vs `create-react-native-app` and then ejecting?

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

Let me preface this by saying that I am **NOT** asking about the difference between CRNA and `react-native`.

I am wondering, that if I use `react-native init` from the start instead of using `create-react-native-app` and then ejecting, what will the difference be between the final application bundle?

Comment: How about upvoters? :)

Comment: @Yossi would be glad if they did too ;)

Comment: So here it is: the question seems fine and legitimate :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two git repo's you can have a look at to compare the project structure:

https://github.com/brookemitchell/blank_react_native_init_project

https://github.com/brookemitchell/blank_create_react-native_app_project

The main differences I see are the react-native version in `package.json`, and the babel presets used in `.babelrc`, maybe there are others.

The difference you would see in the final bundle would be up to you. I have a long since ejected create-react-native app that doesn't use expo sdk anymore, and keeps up with the latest react-native version.